# Problem with Django APP deployment to Heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql, heroku

I've got a problem that I can't find a solution.

I've already tried to deploy to `Heroku` with `mysql` and `postgresql`, and I've always had some kind of a error.

The app works just fine in local environment.

The log:

```py
Cannot execute silk_profile as silk is not installed correctly.

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 230, in ensure_connection

    self.connect()

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner

    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 211, in connect

    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner

    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 199, in get_new_connection

    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect

    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)

psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused

    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>

    main()

  File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line

    utility.execute()

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute

    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 373, in run_from_argv

    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 417, in execute

    output = self.handle(*args, **options)

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 90, in wrapped

    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 75, in handle

    self.check(databases=[database])

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 438, in check

    all_issues = checks.run_checks(

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 77, in run_checks

    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 34, in check_all_models

    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1307, in check

    *cls._check_indexes(databases),

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1699, in _check_indexes

    connection.features.supports_covering_indexes or

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__

    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/features.py", line 84, in is_postgresql_11

    return self.connection.pg_version >= 110000

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__

    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 339, in pg_version

    with self.temporary_connection():

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 119, in __enter__

    return next(self.gen)

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 614, in temporary_connection

    with self.cursor() as cursor:

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner

    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in cursor

    return self._cursor()

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 246, in _cursor

    self.ensure_connection()

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner

    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 230, in ensure_connection

    self.connect()

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__

    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 230, in ensure_connection

    self.connect()

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner

    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 211, in connect

    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner

    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 199, in get_new_connection

    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect

    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)

django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused

    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

`Psql` is running on local and `silk` is installed. When I tried with `mysql` I also encountered a connection problem.

I am following every steps every time but I can't locate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't connect a Django app deployed on Heroku with a local DB but you must use a public DB with a specific service, for example you can use AWS RDS.

Comment: its not deployed with local DB, its deployed with Heroku Postgresql. Thats why i dont understand this error. I've connected de DB in heroku with DATABASE_URL.

heroku config:set DATABASE_URL=postgres://.......